# Openshift overwrites postgresql.conf during restart?

Tags: git, openshift, postgresql-9.2, restart

`enter code here`I am developing a `node.js` application connecting to a Postgresql 9.2 instance. I have configured the database for SSL connections only. This includes setting `ssl = on` in the `postgresql.conf` file.

Everything worked fine, I could connect from my local PC and from PgAdmin to the database. It would only accept SSL connections.

This morning, I have git pushed some of my local work back to Openshift. But, I am systematically getting the following error message:

```
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for
/var/lib/openshift/52e625a44382ec6c7b000042/postgresql
```

I have checked my DB configuration and noticed that `ssl = on` had disappeared in my `postgresql.conf` file. I put it again and could connect to my database. But, when I restarted the application again, it seemed like `postgresql.conf` was overwritten by Openshift again.

How can I prevent/solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

From IRC chat, this is a bug. I have reported the issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is being implemented, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121727